# Is it safe to use operator [] for std::string

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm fighting with an old c-style-interface. I have a function with a signature like this:

```
 /// if return_value == NULL only the length is returned
 void f( char * return_value, size_t * size_only_known_at_runtime);
```

My question is, is the following code safe?

```
std::size required;
f( NULL, &required );
std::string s;
s.resize(required);
f( &s[0], &required );
```

Is there a better way to get the data into the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, at least explicitly from C++11. From [string.require], emphasis mine:

> The char-like objects in a `basic_string` object **shall be stored contiguously**. That is, for any basic_string
>   object s, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.

This was the resolution of [DR 530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530). Before C++11, this was not explicit in the standard, although it was done in practice anyway.

In C++14, this requirement got moved to [basic.string]:

> A `basic_string` is a contiguous container (23.2.1).

where [container.requirements.general]:

> A *contiguous container* is a container that supports random access iterators (24.2.7) and whose member
>   types `iterator` and `const_iterator` are contiguous iterators (24.2.1).

where [iterator.requirements.general]:

> Iterators that further satisfy the requirement that, for integral values `n` and dereferenceable iterator values
>   `a` and `(a + n)`, `*(a + n)` is equivalent to `*(addressof(*a) + n)`, are called *contiguous iterators*.

Comment: Is there also a guarantee about it being null-terminated or not?

Comment: @MicroVirus No. The inequality is `< s.size()`, not `<=`. (Although in practice, yes, not sure how you could implement a constant-time `c_str()` otherwise)

Comment: Note that since we are talking about C++11 already, there is now also a handy member function for this, [`s.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), which is arguably more readable than the good old `&s[0]`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS That one is `const`. You might be confusing with `std::vector`, which does have a non-`const` version of `data()`.

Comment: @Cicada Surprisingly, you are right. I hate `std::string`. :D

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Naw, I'm OK with just upvoting yours.

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether the code

```
std::size_t required_size;
f( nullptr, &required_size );
std::string s;
s.resize( required_size );
f( &s[0], &required_size );
```

is safe.

That depends on which C++ standard one assumes, but since it's Undefined Behavior for the case of `required_size` = 0 in C++03 and C++98, the general answer is **no**, it's not safe in general.

---

In C++03 `std::string` was not formally guaranteed to have a contiguous buffer, but in practice all extant implementation did have contiguous buffer. Anyway, now after C++11, where the contiguous buffer guarantee was formally incorporated in the standard, there will not appear any new C++03 implementations with non-contiguous buffer. Hence that isn't a problem.

The problem is rather that in C++03 `std::basic_string::operator[]` was defined as follows:

**C++03 §21.3.4/1**:

> **”** **Returns:** If `pos < size()`, returns `data()[pos]`. Otherwise, if `pos == size()`, the `const` version returns `charT()`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So, for a non-`const` string `s` of size 0, in C++03 it was Undefined Behavior™ to do the indexing `s[0]`.

In C++11 the corresponding paragraph §21.4.3/2 says instead that the result is “`*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.”

---

Here's code that works regardless of which C++ standard the compiler implements:

```
std::size_t required_size;
f( NULL, &required_size );    // Establish required buffer size.
if( required_size > 0 )
{
    std::string s( required_size, '#' );
    f( &s[0], &required_size );
    s.resize( strlen( &s[0] ) );
}
```